# Validate input word using Scanner.hasNext()

Tags: java, validation, java.util.scanner

I've been reading validation for user input if it is not a number or if input isn't a character, but how do I check if the user input is something I defined for them?

```
System.out.println("What meal would you like to eat?"
        + " (appetizer, soup, salad, main, or dessert)");
String meal = console.next();
```

I saw

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter a vowel, lowercase!");
while (!sc.hasNext("[aeiou]")) {
    System.out.println("That's not a vowel!");
    sc.next();
}
```

but compiler does not like when i change

```
(!sc.hasNext("[aeiou]"))
```

to

```
(!sc.hasNext("[appetizer, soup, salad, main, dessert]"))
```

Comment: You can't make up stuff. What does the string mean (the documentation says)?

Comment: Because that isn't a valid pattern. See: [hasNext(String pattern)](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/scanner_hasnext_string.htm)

Comment: hmmm try `sc.hasNext("appetizer|soup|salad|main|dessert")`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want to try it this way (you also can use enums instead of a `HashSet`):

```
System.out.println("What meal would you like to eat?"
        + " (appetizer, soup, salad, main, or dessert)");
HashSet<String> vowels = new HashSet<String>();
vowels.add("appetizer");
vowels.add("soup");
vowels.add("salad");
vowels.add("main");
vowels.add("dessert");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Please enter a vowel, lowercase!");
while (sc.hasNext()) {
    String vowel = sc.next();
    if (vowels.contains(vowel)) {
        System.out.println("That's a vowel!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("That's not a vowel!");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows. Check if the user's input is inside an array of permitted values.

```
List<String> meals = Arrays.asList(
    new String[]{"appetizer", "soup", "salad","main","dessert"});
String meal = console.next().toLowercase();
if(meals.contains(meal)){
    //Do what you want with correct input.
}
```